# How to read multi-line input in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, line

I want store in a file and in a variable multiples lines from a "paste" via shell script. A simple `read` terminates after the first line.

How can I accomplish that?

Example:

```
echo "Paste the  certificate key:" 

1fv765J85HBPbPym059qseLx2n5MH4NPKFhgtuFCeU2ep6B19chh4RY7ZmpXIvXrS7348y0NdwiYT61
1RkW75vBjGiNZH4Y9HxXfQ2VShKS70znTLxlRPfn3I7zvNZW3m3zQ1NzG62Gj1xrdPD7M2rdE2AcOr3
Pud2ij43br4K3729gbG4n19Ygx5NGI0212eHN154RuC4MtS4qmRphb2O9FJgzK8IcFW0sTn71niwLyi
JOqBQmA5KtbjV34vp3lVBKCZp0PVJ4Zcy7fd5R1Fziseux4ncio32loIne1a7MPVqyIuJ8yv5IJ6s5P
485YQX0ll7hUgqepiz9ejIupjZb1003B7NboGJMga2Rllu19JC0pn4OmrnxfN025RMU6Qkv54v2fqfg
UmtbXV2mb4IuoBo113IgUg0bh8n2bhZ768Iiw2WMaemgGR6XcQWi0T6Fvg0MkiYELW2ia1oCO83sK06
2X05sU4Lv9XeV7BaOtC8Y5W7vgqxu69uwsFALripdZS7C8zX1WF6XvFGn4iFF1e5K560nooInX514jb
0SI6B1m771vqoDA73u1ZjbY7SsnS07eLxp96GrHDD7573lbJXJa4Uz3t0LW2dCWNy6H3YmojVXQVYA1
v3TPxyeJD071S20SBh4xoCCRH4PhqAWBijM9oXyhdZ6MM0t2JWegRo1iNJN5p0IhZDmLttr1SCHBvP1
kM3HbgpOjlQLU8B0JjkY8q1c9NLSbGynKTbf9Meh95QU8rIAB4mDH80zUIEG2qadxQ0191686FHn9Pi
```

read it and store it file say /tmp/keyfile
read it and store it in a variable $keyvariable

Comment: What does "read not working" mean?  What do you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Normally read command is used for storing stdin, but in this case its useless since usually the piece of code provided via paste and it has several lines. Actually  I dont have idea how to do that

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You just have to decide how much to read.

If this is the only input, you could read until end of file. This is how most UNIX utilities work:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Pipe in certificate, or paste and it ctrl-d when done"
keyvariable=$(cat)
```

If you want to continue reading things later in the script, you can read until you see a blank line:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Paste certificate and end with a blank line:"
keyvariable=$(sed '/^$/q')
```

If you want it to feel more like magic interactively, you could read until the script has gone two seconds without input:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Paste your certificate:"
IFS= read -d '' -n 1 keyvariable   
while IFS= read -d '' -n 1 -t 2 c
do
    keyvariable+=$c
done
echo "Thanks!"
```

Comment: Awesome dude. I love you:D

Comment: The latest one is great : works great when I type. But if I paste an answer, it echoes it very weirdly (and almost as many times as there are characters, apparently)... any hint?

Comment: To elaborate: when I paste something: it seems to echo at each loop the remaining buffer to be read... (I can see that by adding a "echo >&2" before the keyvariable+= assignement...) : I'm trying to find a stty setting to avoid this (AIX bash)

Comment: The "magic" version is very clever. Thank  you!

Comment: Not sure why this is closed...was going to add another answer, but: cat | othercmd should do the trick on the bash command line too. Specifically I was trying to minify some JS without saving it to file, so I used: cat | uglifyjs --expr . Addl., small note that there doesn't seem to be an equivalent command for fish (my usual shell)

Comment: cat | minjson && echo -e '\n' works better than my previous answer.

Comment: @smaudet The `cat` serves no purpose. You can just paste directly into `uglifyjs --expr`. And you can do that because uglifyjs uses the one of the techniques outlined above.

Comment: @thatotherguy not really...if all you want to do is use uglifyjs, maybe, but I remember a) uglifyjs did work as you describe and it was actually less useful b) it was hopeless when trying to pipe it elsewhere. So, no, actually I remember it being very useful. Maybe just not useful to you.

Comment: @smaudet Do you have an example of a case where it was hopeless?

Comment: @thatotherguy - unfortunately, no - it looks like this happened about a month or so ago, and I've since changed laptops. I didn't gist it either.

If I had to guess my use case, it was something along the lines of piping to jq to extract a single property.

Its also possible uglifyjs has improved since then, so I don't know that this argument is here nor there. The point is, if your tool you are piping too (such as uglifyjs) is lacking in its design, cat is a useful tool that only requires three characters, compared to your answers which are much lengthier.

Comment: And yes, I realize you are using cat in one of your answers. :)

Comment: Well, these answers are for *writing* a new tool that can be pasted to. They are not for pasting to a tool that already exists. If you want to paste into an existing tool like `jq`, this question and answer does not apply.