# Remote SSH - executing cat and reading input

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, remote-access, remote-server

I've got the following script snippit I've written and am using:

`ssh -t root@$host bash -c "'
   echo \"Connected to server $host\"
   echo \"Paste in data and hit Ctrl + D\"
   data=$(cat)
   echo \"Success!\"
   echo $data
'"`

It works fine without the `cat` line and executes in order.

With the cat line, it hangs for input before any of the echos and then when you `Ctrl + D` it executes the rest.

How can I get this to run back in the intended order?

EDIT:

For clarity, I'm simply attempting to get data from the local console after making the SSH connection. If I was to use a `read`, this works fine and prompts. But if I use "$(cat)" (which works fine locally) I have issues.

I'm attempting to take multiple lines of text in after the SSH connection. I'm using `$(cat)` to do this as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20913871/1511249), which works fine locally but doesn't appear to work in remote commands via SSH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the `cat` happens at the start is because you are using double quotes.  The `$(cat)` is evaluated and executed locally before the `ssh` command runs.  To prevent that, use single quotes instead.  (I took the liberty to simplify a bit more at the same time.)

```
ssh -t root@$host "echo 'Connected to server $host'"';
    echo "Paste in data and hit Ctrl + D"
    data=$(cat)
    echo "Success!"
    echo "$data"'
```

(The first `echo` is in double quotes in order to allow `$host` to be expanded locally; then we switch to single quotes to protect the rest of the command line from local expansion.)

Comment: Note also that `echo "$data"` needs to have double quotes in order to preserve line breaks etc in the input.

Comment: Fantastic, this does the job exactly! Makes sense too, evaluation because it's in double quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1- Using **`variables`** in **`ssh`** connection would be something like this:

```
while read pass port user ip fileinput fileoutput filetemp; do
     sshpass -p$pass ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p $port $user@$ip fileinput=$fileinput fileoutput=$fileoutput filetemp=$filetemp 'bash -s'<<ENDSSH1
     python /path/to/f.py $fileinput $fileoutput $filetemp
     ENDSSH1
done  <<____HERE1
     PASS    PORT    USER    IP    FILE-INPUT    FILE-OUTPUT    FILE-TEMP
____HERE1
```

So you can change this script in the way you want.

2- Can't you change your script to this way?

```
ssh -t root@$host bash -c "'
   echo \"Connected to server $host\"
   echo \"Paste in data and hit Ctrl + D\"
   data=`cat <input-file>`
   echo \"Success!\"
   echo $data
'"
```

3- If you want to run some commands on remote machine try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT='
<put your commands here>
'

while read pass ip; do
    sshpass -p$pass ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p <port> root@$ip "$Script"
done <<HERE
pass1 ip1
pass2 ip2
pass3 ip3
  .    .
  .    .
  .    .
HERE
```

Comment: I don't really understand your first example, it appears over complicated and I assume the python and loop are un-needed?

The latter (using two tildes) results in the same issue as initially.

Comment: Yes...If you want to run commands such running python or run a command over linux like `cat` and if it has a variable you should do something like this...And it surely works...How do you see the second one?[cat should have input file]

Comment: Your third solution is perfectly fine for executing remote commands, however I still have issues with $(cat) and the order, same issue as before.

Comment: see $(cat) is wrong..$(cat file) and `cat file` are correct...try to use data=`cat file` put cat between ` and `

Comment: I'm not attempting to cat a file, I'm attempting to prompt for a multi-line input. I've gotten $(cat) from another SO link and it appears to work fine locally, however not remotely, which is my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20913871/1511249

Comment: I'll certainly upvote the answer when it answers the question! :)