# How to read multiple line of text from console and then save the content to a file with line break?

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

It is because the users do not know how to use vi, I need to create a solution to let the user create a file in the AIX server using a copy and paste.

I refer to the solution from the below link:

[How to read multi-line input in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913635/how-to-read-multi-line-input-in-a-bash-script)

I create a script as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Paste the Bulletin:"
IFS= read -d '' -n 1 keyvariable   
while IFS= read -d '' -n 1 -t 2 c
do
    keyvariable+="$c"$'\n'
done
echo $keyvariable >abc.txt
echo "Thanks!"
```

The input:

```
sdsdfsdfsd
4354353453
/*-/*/-/--/`
```

Expected the abc.txt content:

```
sdsdfsdfsd
4354353453
/*-/*/-/--/
```

Actual the abc.txt content:

```
sd s d f s d f s d 4 3 5 4 3 5 3 4 5 3  /*- /* /-/- - /
```

Unfortunately, the line breaks in the original text do not preserve, so how can I preserve the line breaks and then write the text to the output file?

Comment: If you have `bash` on you AIX, then you can do this: `keyvariable+="$c"$'\n'`

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Consider also just `echo "Paste the Bulletin; hit Control-D on its own line when you're done"; cat > abc.txt"` and avoid a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have bash on your AIX, then you can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Paste the Bulletin:"
while IFS= read -r -t 2 c
do
    keyvariable+="$c"$'\n'
done
echo "$keyvariable" >abc.txt
echo "Thanks!"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simplification / alternative, consider a slight change in workflow and just do this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Paste the Bulletin; hit Control-D on its own line when you're done"
cat > abc.txt
```